# How to know the z-index of two elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position, z-index

I have two carousels which one of them is set to absolute and a toggle button above them which switches them out when I switch to the second one.

I can't click it, I feel the error is from z-index but I didn't set any z-index on any of the elements, is there a plugin to  view their z-index?

Comment: You should be able to use javascript to get the elements z-index like so; console.log(document.getElementById("element").style.zIndex);

Comment: Please show us your code. The button could be overlayed by one of those carousels or some other element.

Comment: You can try this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/devtools-z-index/bcnpmhefiohkpmjacfoanhbjhikegmoe?hl=en

Comment: Notice that while all answers so far show you how to find whether an element has a `z-index` applied, none of the approaches will tell you which [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) an element belongs to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using chrome, you can check it in developer tools.

Right click on the element you want to check and inspect element. Switch to elements tab in developer tool then click on **computed** tab. It shows you all computed styles in alphabetical order.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I missed the point of the question, but simply using 'inspect' on Firefox or Chrome will allow you to see all styling properties on all element.

To get there:

1. Right click the element you want
2. Select 'inspect element'

[image: firebug]
*as you can see the header of this very page has a z-index value of 5050*

Answer (score 0):

You can get the element, then extract the styles. Then you can get the value of style property by using camelcase for the css attribute name.

```
const style = getComputedStyle((document.getElementById("element"));

const zIndex = style.zIndex;

console.log(zIndex);
```